# C# ASP.NET Parse JSON into Dataset without JSON.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Unfortunately I only have access to a .aspx and .aspx.cs file, I can't use third party libraries like JSON.NET

```
    string rawJSON = "{\"Task\":\"IR-C\",\"Staff\":\"Doe\"}";

    JavaScriptSerializer JSS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Dictionary<string, object> parsedObj = JSS.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(rawJSON);

    //string strTask = parsedObj["Task"].toString();
    string strTask = parsedObj["Task"].ToString();
    string strStaff = parsedObj["Staff"].ToString();

    lblWebService.Text = "Task: " + strTask + ", Staff: " + strStaff;
```

I can use the above code if there is a single entry.  But when I try to do more than one I get an error.

```
Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' is not supported for deserialization of an array.
```

The JSON result I get is formatted like this (I'm having trouble creating a string to test with)

```
[
 {"Task":"IR-C",
  "Staff":"Doe"
 },
 {"Task":"DVI",
  "Staff":"Jones"
 },
 {"Task":"Away",
  "Staff":"Smith"
 }
]
```

It's a pretty simple layout, there is only one level to it.  I am trying to figure out how to put this into a C# Dataset but most examples I have found reference JSON.NET which I am not able to use.

Comment: "Unfortunately I only have access to a .aspx and .aspx.cs file" ...what do you mean? You are hand editing the code on the server using notepad, or what? What is the actual restriction in your environment which stops you using the best tools for the job? It sounds like a strange way to work. Can you not fix that issue, rather than searching for workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your situation is the next, what you are trying to deserialize is not a dictionary, is an array/list, to solve this you can create a class with those two properties:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Task { get; set; }
    public string Staff { get; set; }
}
```

and later you can use it to deserialize youy JSON like this:

```
 List<MyClass> parsedObj = JSS.Deserialize<List<MyClass>>(rawJSON);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class in the same file, with some name having two properties.

```
    public class TestClass
    {
    public string Task
        {
        get; set;
        }
    public string Staff
        {
        get; set;
        }
    }
```

and the have the other code to deserialize without using Newtonsoft.Json library, you can directly deserialize.

```
        string rawJSON = "[\r\n {\"Task\":\"IR-C\",\r\n  \"Staff\":\"Doe\"\r\n },\r\n {\"Task\":\"DVI\",\r\n  \"Staff\":\"Jones\"\r\n },\r\n {\"Task\":\"Away\",\r\n  \"Staff\":\"Smith\"\r\n }\r\n]";
        JavaScriptSerializer JSS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<TestClass> parsedObj = JSS.Deserialize<List<TestClass>>(rawJSON);
        foreach ( var obj in parsedObj )
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Task: " + obj.Task + ", Staff: " + obj.Staff);
            }
```